# SQL Eliminate one result after join

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, duplicates

I am coming across a common problem when joining tables where I get two results for each condition and I need to eliminate one.

For example I am now trying to find out what stock of a product code I have and if I have anything on order and when it is due in. I only want to see each product code once and it was working fine when I was just showing the quantity on order, but now I want the due date I had to do a left join. Now I am getting two results for each product code. I am getting one showing what it has in stock and another one if there is something on order and when its due in. I only want to see stock if nothing on order and stock and order as one line if there is something on order, not both seperately.

```
DECLARE @cat VARCHAR(150) 

SET @cat = 'crumb' --Put your search string in the single speech marks 
SELECT category_treeview_node.ctn_description               AS 
       [Product Category], 
       variant_detail.vad_variant_code                      AS [Variant Code], 
       variant_detail.vad_description                       AS 
       [Variant Description], 
       Sum(variant_transaction_header.vth_current_quantity) AS [Physical Stock], 
       variant_stock_quantity.vasq_free_stock_quantity      AS [Free Stock], 
       variant_stock_location.vsl_stock_on_purchase_order   AS [Stock on order], 
       purchase_order_header.poh_required_date              AS [Due Date] 
FROM   variant_stock_quantity 
       INNER JOIN (variant_detail 
                   INNER JOIN variant_category 
                           ON variant_detail.vad_id = 
                              variant_category.vac_vad_id 
                   INNER JOIN category_treeview_node 
                           ON category_treeview_node.ctn_id = 
                              variant_category.vac_ctn_id) 
               ON variant_stock_quantity.vasq_vad_id = variant_detail.vad_id 
       INNER JOIN variant_stock_location 
               ON variant_detail.vad_id = variant_stock_location.vsl_vad_id 
       LEFT JOIN (variant_transaction_header_total 
                  INNER JOIN variant_transaction_header 
                          ON variant_transaction_header_total.vtht_vth_id = 
                             variant_transaction_header.vth_id) 
              ON variant_detail.vad_id = variant_transaction_header.vth_vad_id 
       LEFT JOIN purchase_order_line 
              ON purchase_order_line.pol_id = 
                 variant_transaction_header.vth_pol_id 
                 AND variant_detail.vad_id = purchase_order_line.pol_vad_id 
       LEFT JOIN purchase_order_header 
              ON purchase_order_header.poh_id = purchase_order_line.pol_poh_id 
WHERE  category_treeview_node.ctn_description = @cat 
GROUP  BY category_treeview_node.ctn_description, 
          variant_detail.vad_variant_code, 
          variant_detail.vad_description, 
          variant_stock_quantity.vasq_free_stock_quantity, 
          variant_stock_location.vsl_stock_on_purchase_order, 
          purchase_order_header.poh_required_date 
HAVING variant_stock_quantity.vasq_free_stock_quantity >= 0
```

Im getting one result which shows the physical stock, the free stock, whats on order and a due date of null and then one result which shows no physical stock, the free stock, whats on order and the due date.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please add a tag for your RDBMS (SQL Server?).

Comment: Please show actual output and expected output. This makes it a lot easier to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: code    item       phys         free            on order due
NB03 Breadcrumb 346.0000 306.0000 80.0000 
NB03 Breadcrumb 0.0000 306.0000 80.0000 15/02/2013

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the requested information. That database engine you use is crucial information that must be in your post and tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question. But in general, you don't want to use SQL to do what you're describing. Use SQL to return the data (like your query does now), and use a report writer to hide repeating values, summarize data in headers and footers, etc.

It's a simple division of labor. SQL returns the data; report writers (or their equivalent) handle the presentation and layout.